# Text & arrow on the button

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/G6Wj6/

in CSS the text will not move up with vertical-align:center; and the left padding will not move the arrow about 10px away from the edge of the button. I tried different ways to fix this issue and couldnt solve this.

HTML

```
<div class="FindHome">
    <h1>Find your home</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.FindHome 
{
background-color:#09F; 
width:250px;
height:50px;
border:1px solid #09F; 
padding:0px 20px 0px 0px; 
border-radius:5px; 
display:block; 
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto; 
background: #09F url('http://www.magnixsolutions.com/clients/tas/img/arrow.png') no-repeat; 
background-position:right; 
vertical-align: center;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: vertical-align:center does not work but middle. And will not vertical align the child content. @See http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `height` to get the text to vertically align

The background position can be changed to:

```
background-position: 240px center;
```

to get it close to the right edge

http://jsfiddle.net/G6Wj6/5/

Comment: Removing the height from the div is not a complete solution since now your div height is 80px, because you didn't reset default browser margin on `h1`.

Comment: think of my answer as an alternate solution to yours, not a wrong one

Answer (score 0):

Reset `h1` top and bottom margin that gets added by default from browser to `0` and set a `line-height` equal to your `div` `height` (or use `padding` if you are planning to have multiline text) to center the text.

Than to offset the background arrow `10px` from right border, you need to move it as background of `h1` and apply a margin and padding directly to the h1 tag while leaving the background color on your `div` element.

In the end just set background position to `center right` - this will keep it 10px from the right edge no matter even if you later change your `div` `width` to something other than `250px`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gmx8w/

```
.FindHome 
{
    background-color:#09F; 
    width:250px;
    height:50px;

    border:1px solid #09F; 
    padding:0; 
    border-radius:5px; 
    display:block; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    background: #09F;
    background-position:right; 
    vertical-align: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.FindHome h1 {
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
    padding:0 20px 0 0;
    line-height:50px;
    background: url('http://www.magnixsolutions.com/clients/tas/img/arrow.png') no-repeat center right; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/G6Wj6/25/

The arrow was too close to the edge. Moved the background to the H1 element.There is no need to vertical-align anything as the border-radius and top and bottom padding are equal values.

```
.FindHome {
background-color:#09F;
width:250px;
border:1px solid #09F;
border-radius:5px;
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
}

.FindHome h1 {
margin: 0;
padding:10px;
background:#09F url(http://www.magnixsolutions.com/clients/tas/img/arrow.png) no-repeat 225px 50%;
}
```